# How to use kotlin as a server side lanaguage?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to develop server side application like a blog app, So how can i use kotlin programming  language as a server side language.

Answer (score 0):

> Ktor is a framework for building asynchronous servers and clients in connected systems using the powerful Kotlin programming language. This website provides a complete reference to the Ktor application structure and programming interface. And how to approach particular tasks.

[Ktor offcial site](https://ktor.io/)